# java - copy files from mobile device

Tags: java, android, file, storage, mobile-devices

I'd been trying to make this little desktop java application to backup some predefined files from an android tablet/smartphone to my computer.

Up to now I'd been using mainly the File.getRoots() function to reach every single drive with no trouble. I successfully tested this on two android phones, but the problem came when I tried it on a Galaxy Note. Unlike the first two. this device is not treated as "removable media" but as a "mobile device". Therefore, I can't reach it using my current method, it's just not "listed".

I'd also looked if there's a way to reach those mobile devices through cmd, hoping that helps, but haven't found anything usefull.

My goal is to backup just by plug > run-application > unplug.

So, that's it, i'm stuck! Any clue?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: adb should work through cmd, right?

Comment: Have you made sure you have the correct setting on the phone? Have you tried the latest driver http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SGH-I717ZBAATT or if that didn't work -- tried Kies. adb is probably a good idea. Also perhaps consider backing up over bluetooth, local wifi, over the internet, (or even over gmail since most Android phone owners have an existing gmail account).

Comment: i'll try with the phone settings when i can ask for it again (friend's phone). the target user non-computer-related person, and i think it'll be better to keep stuff wired. anyways the gmail option sounds interesting too. thanks for the answers:D